# communicating between classes with pointers

Tags: objective-c, class, pointers, cocos2d-iphone

Hi all,
I'm having a hard time understanding how to use pointers 
(my first time using them) hoping someone can point me in the right 
direction (no pun intended) :P
(it controls the sound,pagenumber,bg,audio int, and text to be displayed) 
(NSString *)**textFromPlist** pointer which points to the plist containing the text for **@"Page01Text"**
I want to take **@"Page01Text"** and use it in the **HighLighter class**

I am able to log the output for the sound,pagenumber,bg,audio int, and text etc in the hello world layer (its logging the `TextManagerWithpageNum`) so I know that the plist is reading, 
but for some reason I cant link **textFromPlist**  I'd like to be able to use the `textFromPlist` from the `TextManagerWithpageNum` class and let the hilighter class work with it (this class will hilight the text and work with the audio intervals supplied by the plist)
this piece of code it returns (NULL)

```
    @interface HighLighter.h

    TextManagerWithpageNum *myClassAccess; 
    //declaring the TextManagerWithpageNum class so I can access textFromPlist


    @implementation HighLighter.m
     -(NSString *)Sentance01 
    {
    NSString *textFromTextManager = myClassAccess.textFromPlist;
    NSString *storyText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textFromTextManager];
        return [[[NSString alloc]initWithString:StoryText]autorelease]; 
        //doesn't crash but doesn't load text

    NSLog(@"text form plist @%",storyText);

    }
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? (I have an int array I also wish to link, but thought I'd start with the `NSString` as I thought this would be simpler.)
any help would be wonderful, kind regards,
Natalie.

```
    @interface TextManagerWithpageNum : CCLayer
    NSString* textFromPlist_Pntr;
    @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString* textFromPlist;
   //NSString* textFromPlist is an item on the plist  @"page01"  which contains text for  the page

   @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString* audioInterval;
   //NSString* AudioInterval is an array on the plist  @"AudioTimings_PG01"

   @implementation TextManagerWithpageNum
   @synthesize textFromPlist = textFromPlist_Pntr;
   @synthesize audioInterval = _audioInterval;
```

Comment: It would help if you post your real code: `storyText` is written in the next line as `StoryText`, and the `NSLog` *cannot* print anything because it follows the `return` statement.

Comment: It is very unwise to attempt to learn Objective-C without *first* having a good comprehension of pointers.  You should start with C first, then graduate to Objective-C when you're reasonably competent with C.  The world can wait a few months for your fantastic viral app.

Comment: Sorry, this "learn C first" advice is bollocks. It is *almost always* best to learn the topics in the context of the language one has chosen to learn. Not doing so will also teach a beginner all the things she has to unlearn when she does upgrade to the other language. Like yes, it's perfectly valid in ObjC to send a message to a nil pointer - just won't do anything (not even crash). Or no, you don't use malloc to allocate memory for a class instance. Etc etc.

Comment: Best advice at this point: do use ARC, makes life with pointers much easier. Also: the NSLog after the return statement will never execute due to the return. And you can just return storyText, you don't need to create a new string (even if you did, you could just send it the 'copy' method).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks would agree about ARC (your Enabling ARC in a Cocos2D tutorial BTW was great!)  Most likely its a memory problem...that I'm not retaining something I should be - or some other little weird bug... (that or a conceptual problem - scientific for doing something dumb ;P)...still I'll have a look through all your good advice that you have all been kind enough to send - each piece makes a more complete picture and helps a great deal - cheers Natty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options when communicating any data between classes.  I will show both, using an example `SomeData` object that is being sent from `ObjectA` to `ObjectB`.  You can also use class level methods to, for example, send or receive data in a pointer to a singleton object.  I won't show you how to do that because it doesn't sound like that fits your problem.

**Option 1**

Define a receiving message in `ObjectB`.

```
@interface ObjectA
{
    SomeData *someDataPointer;
    ObjectB *someObjectB;
}
@end

@implementation ObjectA

-(void)someMethod
{
    someDataPointer = [[SomeData alloc] init]; // Or whatever way you want to create and set someDataPointer
    [someObjectB receiveData:someDataPointer];

    // Note: if you will be calling receiveData on someObjectB much later than the
    //    time of creation of someDataPointer, you should retain someDataPointer to
    //    hold onto it until you need to pass it on.
    //    ie)
    // [someDataPointer retain];
}

@end

@interface ObjectB
-(void)receiveData:(SomeData *)dataPtr;
@end

@implementation ObjectB

-(void)receiveData(SomeData *)dataPtr
{
    // Here the data from someDataPointer will also be pointed to by dataPtr
    // Use dataPtr now
    [self doSomethingWithData:dataPtr];
}

@end
```

**Option 2**

Define a sending message in `ObjectA`.

```
@interface ObjectA
{
    SomeData *someDataPointer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeData *someDataPointer;

@end

@implementation ObjectA
@synthesize someDataPointer = someDataPointer_;
@end

@interface ObjectB
{
    ObjectA *someObjectA;
}
@end

@implementation ObjectB

-(void)someMethod
{
    SomeData *dataPtr = [someObjectA getSomeDataPointer];
    // Now do something with dataPtr
}

@end
```

I hope that helps.  I wanted to show you these two techniques generally so that you can learn to apply it to your case specifically.  Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you so much Keifer, its such a good clear explanation, and just what I needed!, it might take a little time to get my piece of code going in relation to this problem, but every bit of good information goes a long way to make this possible - I may have questions a little later, but for now I'm off to play with the code!

Comment: Glad to help!  If it works out for you, the culture on Stack Overflow is to upvote the answer you like and click the check-mark to designate the best answer.